# VirtualBox VM w/ Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Resolution Problems (already installed virtualbox-guest-dkms)

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I created a new VM with the latest version of Ubuntu, but I can't get the resolution to go above 640x480.

I have installed the packages virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-utils, but virtualbox-guest-x11 failed to install due to missing xorg core dependency, but I ignored it since most people say it's not required.

I have video memory turned up to 128 mb.

If I open my Software & Update settings, the x86 virtualization service is enabled and running. VM has been rebooted many times.

tl;dr same old resolution problems many people have had, but none of the solutions worked for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Try KVM (virtmanager) + spice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the virtualbox-guest-additions-iso then mount and install it on the guest OS using the option provided on Virtualbox.